# .Net core 1.1 UseResponseCompression isn't compressing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I've just upgraded all my .net core packages to asp.net core 1.1. At the same time I thought I'd implement the newly released response compression middleware. However when I look in the browser dev tools (network traffic), I can see that the response is no different in size whether I use compression or not. Additionally there is no response header of type "Content-Encoding" indicating that compression occurred.

Is there anything else I should be doing here to make this work?

My code is as follow:

```
    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(options => {
            options.CacheProfiles.Add("Never",
                new CacheProfile()
                {
                    Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None,
                    NoStore = true,
                    Duration = 0
                });
        });

        services.AddResponseCompression();
```

And:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        appBuilder.UseResponseCompression();
        appBuilder.UseMvc();
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to specify the compression provider.  Try this:

```
        services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        });
```

When I do that I see a response that was previously 89kb go to 2kb and the content type and encoding are being set to expected values.

Comment: I'll give it a go.

Comment: Please also note that HTTPS will not work, you have to also add `options.EnableForHttps = true;`

Comment: @JasonLeung you should post that as an answer! It fixed my problem and I would vote for it.